# Autoplay media until time's up in google dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have working on google actions lately. I need to play an url of mp3 for x minute(this receive from user such as play abc for 30 minutes.). My problem is my mp3 url is only 1.30 minutes long. How can I play it until x minutes. I use dialogflow index.js file for code. Here is what I try

```
app.intent('soundplay', (conv, {soundreq, duration}) => {
    conv.ask(new Suggestions('Exit'));

    conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
        speech: 'xxx',
        text: 'xxx',
    }));

    conv.ask(sound);
    var d = duration.milliseconds;
    setTimeout(sound, d);

});
```

I try to use setTimeout but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues you need to deal with.

The first is that `sound` is pretty vague from your code sample. You're using it in `setTimeout()`, which suggests that it is a function, but you're also passing it to `conv.ask()` which suggests it is a `MediaResponse` or some other object.

The second is that this code will run on your server, not on the user's device, and Actions work in a conversational back-and-forth model. So once you send something to the user, you need to wait until the user (or the user's device) sends you another message that you can reply with.

The solution is to include a [MediaObject](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses) as part of the response you build. This will include the URL of the audio you want to play, along with a title and some other information.

When the audio finishes playing, your Dialogflow agent will get a message with an `actions_intent_MEDIA_STATUS` Event. You can create an Intent that handles this event and, in the Intent Handler for it in your webhook, check to see if the time has expired. If it has, you can prompt for what to do now or end the conversation or whatever is appropriate. If it has not expired, you can play the audio again using another MediaObject.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. 'sound' is MediaObject. I didn't use MediaResponse in my project. Do I must change coding in Inline Editor to Webhook?

Comment: No, the Inline Editor and Webhook are equivalent.

Comment: If the answer helps, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.